# R language "wordcloud" selecting incorrect colors

Tags: r, colors

I try to create a wordcloud in R using different colors depending on the sign of the Amount column (blue for positive amount and red for negative amount). My dataset (stats) is as follows:

```
Currency,Amount,Color,ColorCode
AED,-10.50,red,0
AMD,8.20,blue,1
ARS,11.80,blue,1
AUD,-5.60,red,0
BRL,125.80,blue,1
CAD,-26.30,red,0
CHF,89.60,blue,1
CLF,154.80,blue,1
CLP,-100.23,red,0
CNH,14.25,blue,1
CNY,-10.12,red,0
COP,-60.50,red,0
CZK,-33.25,red,0
DKK,-94.60,red,0
DZD,-14.90,red,0
```

and my code is:

```
<pre><code>
set.seed(1234)
wordcloud(words=stats$Currency, freq=stats$Amount, max.words=Inf, 
          scale=c(9,2), random.order=FALSE, rot.per=0.5, colors=stats$Color)
</code></pre>
```

The generated wordcloud looks as follows:
[wordcloud example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0twL.png)

Notice that currency "AMD" is positive (blue) but it appears as red in the image.

Thank you,

### Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `ordered.colors = TRUE`

```r
library(wordcloud)
set.seed(1234)

wordcloud(words = stats$Currency, freq = stats$Amount, min.freq = -150,
          max.words = 200, random.order = FALSE, rot.per = 0.5, scale = c(6,2),
          colors = stats$Color, ordered.colors = TRUE)
```